# Unexpected call to default constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I don't understand why, during the execution of the following program, the default constructor is called.

I created a class `Location` that has a default constructor, a non default constructor and a copy constructor. They work, but when I try to pass an object `Location` to the constructor of another object `Salesman`, it is automatically called the default constructor. Why?

Here it is the main that I've written to test the program:

```
int main() {
    Location a(1,1);
    Location b;
    Location c(a);

    std::vector<Location> vett;
    std::cout << "\nPROBLEMS: " << std::endl;

    vett.push_back(a);
    vett.push_back(b);
    vett.push_back(c);
    std::cout << "\nPROBLEMS OF A SALESMAN: " << std::endl;

    // here it is called the default constructor! Why?

    Salesman Willy(a, vett.begin(), vett.end());
}
```

The output I get is:

> myconstrct  default  copy
>
> PROBLEMS:  copy  copy  copy  copy  copy  copy
>
> PROBLEMS OF A SALESMAN:  copy  default
>
> Inside Willy (until **):  copy 
>   * copy 
>   * copy  copy 
>   * copy  copy  copy 
>   **

And here there are the classes:

```
class Location {
private:
    double x_, y_;
public:
    Location(double x, double y) : x_(x), y_(y) { std::cout << "myconstrct " << std::endl; }
    Location() {
        std::cout << "default " << std::endl;
        x_ = drand48();
        y_ = drand48();
    }
    Location(const Location & L) : x_(L.x_), y_(L.y_) {
        std::cout << "copy " << std::endl;
     }
};

class Salesman {
private:
    Location start_;
protected:
    std::vector<Location> tobevisited_;
public:
    Salesman(const Location & start, std::vector<Location>::iterator it1, std::vector<Location>::iterator it2) {
        std::cout << "\nInside Willy (until **): " << std::endl;
        Location start_(start);
        for(std::vector<Location>::iterator it = it1; it != it2; it++) {
            std::cout << "*" << std::endl;
            tobevisited_.push_back(*(it));
        }
        std::cout << "**" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: On a side note those are some really bad print statements used for debugging.

Comment: @NathanOliver You mean `Location start_;` right?

Comment: As @GauravSehgal said it's true that if you have a "Location" member inside your Salesman class it's normal to have it's default CTOR call before going inside the "Salesman " CTOR..... member init first !!!!

Comment: In addition to using member initialization for the member start_ -- i.e. : start_(start) -- note that your current code actually redefines start_ locally so its not even changing the start_ member object. Also, you can reduce many of the extraneous copy operations by also initializing tobevisited_ in the list, using the range constructor for the vector -- i.e. tobevisited(it1,it2). Currently some of these are being recopied because iteratively pushing back new elements requires moving the vector.

Comment: @jwimberley Thanks for the suggestions, now it works!